# Confusion about UIView's setNeedsDisplay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, setneedsdisplay

I have an ivar of UITableView* myTableView. I have data being loaded from internet so when the data gets loaded should i call [myTableView setNeedsDisplay], i know i can/should call [myTableView reloadData] but the confusion is that calling setNeedsDisplay should also work but is not working.

I am just looking for an explanation as to what setNeedsDisplay does? when called on UITableView instance.

As per the documentation setNeedsDisplay calls drawRect in "next drawing cycle". so can anyone tell me what is the next drawing cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setNeedsDisplay` marks the calling `UIView` as needing to be redrawn is a purely visual sense, which as stated will happen on the next drawing cycle.

This is completely different to reloading the data when used in a `UITableView` context.

See [this article](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/understanding-reload-repaint-and-re-layout-for-uitableview.html) for a little more information on the subject.

Comment: Link doesn't go to relevant content

Answer (score 6):

*setNeedsDisplay* method has nothing to do with the reloading of the *tableView*. It just redraws the `view` of the *tableView*, not its *cells* or *separators*.

*setNeedsDisplay* and *reloadData* are entirely for different purposes.

Answer (score 2):

**SetNeedsDisplay**

A good example of this is when a *UIImageView* is rendered with one image; and while it is still on screen, you change the image to something else. In this case, just changing the image will not always trigger a repaint of the view, for that to occur you need to make a call to `setNeedsDisplay`.

**reloadData**

It has to be called when the *underlying data source* for the tableview is changed and you want that to be refelected in UI.In that case call this `reloadData` mehod

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you only need to call setNeedsDisplay on custom views for which you have implemented drawRect.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to update all visible cells and keep track of indexPath of cell in my custom class "ProductTableViewCell" with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, see below:

```
NSArray *arrayCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
NSMutableArray *mArrayIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(ProductTableViewCell *cell in arrayCells) {
    [mArrayIndexPaths addObject:cell.indexPath];
}

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[mArrayIndexPaths copy] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Here is how the class is defined:

```
@interface ProductTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    NSString *reuseID;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```